# YOLO - are the anchor boxes used only in training?

Tags: conv-neural-network, yolo, bounding-box

Another question in YOLO. I've red about how YOLO adjusts anchor boxes by offsets to create the final bounding boxes.

What I do not understand, is when YOLO does it. Is it being done only during the training process, or also during the common use of already trained model?

*My guess is that it is being done **ONLY** in training stage, where anchor boxes are being compared to ground-truth box using IoU, and thus start "fitting" the offsets using by lose sunction until they get IoU close to 1. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ignore my previous two posts. The anchor boxes are used in both training and testing with trained model. In my first post when I said the results are the same, it only applies to the detected classes, the bounding boxes are not the same if the anchor box values changed in the config file.

Comment: I see but, fix me please if I am mistaken, anchor box values in the config file are a result of training aren't they?

Comment: No, they are simply calculated with K-means on your training set bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor boxes are only used in training, they are not used during detection using the trained model. You can test this by changing the anchor boxes values to random values on a test set, the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Following up my previous comment, I think the answer is NO and Yes. NO -- the anchor values (initial values) defined in the config file are only used during training, not used when you do detection with the trained model. Yes -- during training those values will be adjusted and saved with the model, and those adjusted values will be used when you do detection with the trained model.